npm игнорируется в VS Code
Установил Node.js на компьютер. npm работает в командной строке, но не в VS Code. При любой попытке взаимодействовать с npm через терминал в VS Code просто происходит перевод на новую строчку. С чем это может быть связано? Спасибо!



После установки перезапускали программу? Если нет то просто перезапустите

Перезапускал. И программу, и компьютер. Не помогло(
